# NLTK SVM Classifier Terminates

Tags: python, python-2.7, nltk, svm

I am using the SVM classifier built in NLTK and after training the model, when I try to classify a document, the program terminates with `Error during execution, QProcess error: 1 Execution Interrupted`

I am using the following code:-

```
classifier = nltk.classify.svm.SvmClassifier.train(train_features)
for test_record in test_data_list:
    features = extract_features(test_record)
    predict = classifier.classify(features)
    print predict
```

What could be the reason for the error?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`nltk.classify.svm` was deprecated. For classification based
on support vector machines SVMs use `nltk.classify.scikitlearn`
(or [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org) directly).For more details [NLTK 3.0 documentation](http://nltk.org/api/nltk.classify.html#module-nltk.classify.svm)

You can use `nltk.classify.scikitlearn` as follows

```
import nltk.classify
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC

classifier = nltk.classify.SklearnClassifier(LinearSVC())
classifier.train(train_features)

for test_record in test_data_list:
    features = extract_features(test_record)
    predict = classifier.classify(features)
    print predict
```

Answer (score 0):

nltk has deprecated svm ,you will have to use scikit - learn to use support vector classification for classifying

You can use :

```
import nltk.classify
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC

classifier = nltk.classify.SklearnClassifier(LinearSVC())
classifier.train(train_set)
from nltk import classify 

accuracy = classify.accuracy(classifier, test_set)
print (accuracy)
```